# add image to jQuery UI autocomplete remote source with cache

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am using jQuery autocomplete remote source with caching. [As per demo by jQUery UI website](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#remote-with-cache) javascript of remote source with caching is

```
<script>
$(function() {
    var cache = {},
        lastXhr;
    $( "#birds" ).autocomplete({
        minLength: 2,
        source: function( request, response ) {
            var term = request.term;
            if ( term in cache ) {
                response( cache[ term ] );
                return;
            }

            lastXhr = $.getJSON( "search.php", request, function( data, status, xhr ) {
                cache[ term ] = data;
                if ( xhr === lastXhr ) {
                    response( data );
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Now I want to add some code to above javascript to display image in autocomplete list. There is an excellent example for displaying image in jQuery autocomplete such as:
http://jsfiddle.net/3zSMG/ but it does not include caching part.

I have been trying but NOT able to integrate this example into the existing remote with caching javascript. Any help would be very much appreciated. Many thanks.

FOLLOW-UP: As suggested by Andrew Whitaker, I have updated my script as follow:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    var cache = {},
        lastXhr;
    $( "#birds" ).autocomplete({
        minLength: 2,
        source: function( request, response ) {
            var term = request.term;
            if ( term in cache ) {
                response(cache[term]);
                return;
            }

            lastXhr = $.getJSON( "search.php", request, function( data, status, xhr ) {
                var results;
                if ( xhr === lastXhr ) {
                    results = $.map(data, function(item) {
                        return {
                        value: item.value,
                        avatar: item.avatar
                        };
                    });
                    cache[term] = results;
                    response(results);
                }                   
            });
        },
    }).data("autocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
    if ( item.value != null ) {
        if ( item.avatar != null) {
            return $("<li/>")
                .data("item.autocomplete", item)
                .append("<a><img src='images/" + item.avatar + "' />" + item.value + "</a>")
                .appendTo(ul);
            }
        else {
            return $("<li/>")
                .data("item.autocomplete", item)
                .append("<a>" + item.value + "</a>")
                .appendTo(ul);
        }
    }
    }; 
});
```

And content of search.php:

```
<?php
require_once "config.php";
$term = trim(strip_tags($_GET['term']));//retrieve the search term that autocomplete sends
$qstring = "select id, subject as value, avatar from Suggests where subject LIKE '%".$term."%'";
$result = mysql_query($qstring);//query the database for entries containing the term
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC))//loop through the retrieved values
{
    $row['value']=htmlentities(stripslashes($row['value']));
    $row['id']=(int)$row['id'];
    $row['avatar']=$row['avatar'];
    $row_set[] = $row;//build an array
}
echo json_encode($row_set);//format the array into json data

?>
```

I am able to see images in autocomplete list. But there is an issue: After keying in few letters, autocomplete list is shown up, if I continue adding some more random letters to expect autcomplete list to disappear (because the userinput no longer matches) but it does not. [Andrew's example work well](http://jsfiddle.net/rK7TS/). Is there anything wrong with my javascript? Trying to debug by Firebug, I got error: TypeError element is null.

[image: err]

Answer (score 3):

The key to the image portion of the demos is overriding the `_renderItem` function to change the `li`'s that are generated to suggest items. This usually means that your source is an array with objects that have a `label` and/or `value` property, as well as a property that allows you to display the image correctly inside of `_renderItem`.

The caching code just stores the search term and results in a hash and looks in that hash before hitting the server.

Using the JSFiddle you linked as an example, here's something using StackOverflow's API that does caching and images:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var cache = {},
        lastXhr;

    $("#auto").autocomplete({
        source: function(request, response) {
            var term = request.term;

            if (term in cache) {
                response(cache[term]);
                return;
            }

            lastXhr = $.ajax({
                url: "http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/users",
                data: {
                    filter: request.term,
                    pagesize: 10
                },
                jsonp: "jsonp",
                dataType: "jsonp",
                success: function(data, status, xhr) {
                    var results;
                    if (xhr === lastXhr) {
                        results = $.map(data.users, function(el, index) {
                            return {
                                value: el.display_name,
                                avatar: "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/" + el.email_hash
                            };
                        });

                        cache[term] = results;
                        response(results);                                 
                    }
                }
            });
        },
        delay: 500
    }).data("autocomplete")._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
        return $("<li />")
            .data("item.autocomplete", item)
            .append("<a><img src='" + item.avatar + "' />" + item.value + "</a>")
            .appendTo(ul);
    };
});​
```

**Notes**:

- This example is more complex than the examples on jQueryUI's website because the data from the API has to be transformed (to have `avatar`/`value` properties). The important thing to note is that we're caching the received values *after* the `$.map` call transforms the result array.
- This looks complicated but just remember the two guidelines at the top of the answer and you should be good.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/rK7TS/

Comment: Thanks Andrew. But there is still an issue: autocomplete list does not disappear when userinput no longer matches.

Comment: your demo throws an error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <`

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did:

```
    lastXhr = $.getJSON( action, request, function( data, status, xhr ) {

        if( data && data !== null ) {
            var results;
            if( xhr === lastXhr ) {
                results = $.map(data, function(item) {
                    return {
                        value: item.value,
                        avatar: item.avatar
                    };
                });
                cache[term] = results;
                response(results);
            }
        } else {
            response([{ value: 'No results found.', avatar: null}]);
        }

    });
```