# How to add image to the textbox autocomplete source

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, autocomplete, html.textbox

I'm using jquery autocomplete to load the values in the textbox:

```
@Html.TextBox("Cities", "", new { @id="tags" })

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
        var availableTags = [
        "New York",
        "London",
        "Moscow",
        "Paris",
        "Berlin",
        "Madrid",
    ];
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
        source: availableTags
    });
});
```

Actually, I have more than 1000 cities and I'm going to store them in the database and send to the view through the model. Also, for more enjoyable appearance I want to add country flag to the drop-down list of my textbox like:

[image]

How can I do it? How to add image to the autocomlete source?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm overriding _renderMenu function in my solution:

```
    _renderMenu: function( ul, items ) {
    var that = this;
    $.each( items, function( index, item ) {
        that._renderItemData( ul, item )
            .children("a")
            .attr("title", item.value["@tooltip"])
            .prepend("<img class='menu_button_img' src='" + item.value["@icon"] + "' /> ");
    });
},
```

Works ok for me :)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I tried to override _RenderItem function and it works! Please, have a look at [ljsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/RsTvq/) And I have one more question: How to select drop-down menu item and make visible country flag in textbox near the sity?

Comment: never did it before. Maybe image outside of input is better: look http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#custom-data

Comment: This is easier than I thought. Just added textbox background-image for the item select event [UPDATED jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/RsTvq/1/)

Answer (score 1):

you have to edit html of your autocomplete source to add flag image ,look into this question [add image to jQuery UI autocomplete remote source with cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12444110/add-image-to-jquery-ui-autocomplete-remote-source-with-cache)